Confused about the rules for verb + infinitive
I'm doing a worksheet in which rules for verbs + infinitive or gerund have to be completed. And there is one rule I'm really not clear about. It says:
"An infinitive is often used to answer the question 'why...?' or to talk about the purpose for doing something. The action is imagined or in the future."
I don't understand the last part about "the action is imagined or in the future". For example, if I say something like "I decided to buy the house because it was cheap", then this is talking about a purpose for doing something, but it's not imagined or in the future. So is the rule as supplied in the worksheet wrong?

At the time of the decision, it was imagined, or let's say envisaged.

"I'm saving up to buy the house" is a better context for "the action is imagined or in the future". It answers the question 'Why are you saving up?' AND talks about the purpose for doing something (saving up).

Can you explain how you see this working, because your complaint is not very clear? I'd guess the sequence of events is 1. I look at a house and inquire about the price. 2. I decide I will buy it. 3. I follow through on my decision and go through the process of buying it. In this sequence, 3 is in the future of 2. Maybe you understand something different.

Sorry it wasn't very clear. The exact sentence from the worksheet was "He put on a pair of running shoes and decided to run into the night." Then the rule given was the one I shared above: "An infinitive is often used to answer the question 'why...?' or to talk about the purpose for doing something. The action is imagined or in the future." The infinitive in this sentence is "decided to run". But I don't understand how that is talking about something imagined or in the future? Hence I gave a different example of usage like "I decided to buy the house because it was cheap".

The "because" PP in your example marks the clause as a purpose adjunct. But the verb+infinitival construction, as in "I decided to buy the house" has the infinitival clause functioning not as an adjunct, but as a complement of "decided". Semantically, it tells us what was decided, not why. Questioning with "what" is possible with some verbs like "decide", e.g. "What did you decide"? "I decided to buy the house".

"An infinitive is often used to answer the question 'why...?' or to talk about the purpose for doing something. The action is imagined or in the future" is less of a "rule" and more of a statement about the typical contexts in which the verb+infinitive is used.
In any case, if your sentence is reformulated in present tenses, then the action is indeed imagined and in the future: "I have decided to buy the house because it is cheap".
And as @fev says in the comment, in the past tense version of your sentence, at the time of the decision the house purchase was imagined and in the future.

Ah so it's talking about in the moment the past action occurred. That's much clearer. Thanks!
